# c# professional error handling

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am trying to learn proffesional error handling techniques, yet I am unable to grasp the concept of them, even though I have read quite a few articles from MSDN and CodePlex.

I will try to demonstrate my concern on a simplified example. My only request in error handling is that I don't want my program to quit, just because an error has occured. I want to be able to see what the error was, but in case there are more errors in the file, I want to see the list of all errors once the process has completed (currently I store all error messages in a variable, which I afterwards flush to a StreamWriter to a file).

I have read that you can handle custom errors using your custom **ApplicationException** classes such as following:

```
public class CustomException : ApplicationException
{
    public CustomException() : base() { }
    public CustomException(string sMessage) : base(sMessage) { }
}
```

And here is the code sample:
First Class that we are working with

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string _Name, int _Age)
    {
        this.Name = _Name;
        this.Age = _Age;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now a class that is used for some work:

```
public class MyWorker
{
    //here we store errors
    public string sErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //reset variables
        sErrorMessage = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            //create new array of employees
            List<Person> Employees = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Steven",30),
            new Person("John",26),
            new Person("Anna",18)
        };

            //first check if value is not null
            if (Employees == null || Employees.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new CustomException("Employee array is empty. Nothing to validate!");
            }

            //Data validation
            foreach (var item in Employees)
            {
                if (item.Name == "John")
                    throw new CustomException("John is not allowed!");

                if (item.Age < 21)
                    throw new CustomException("Person has to be older than 21!");
            }
        }
        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            InsertErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void InsertErrorMessage(string sMessage)
    {
        sErrorMessage += Environment.NewLine + sMessage;
    }
}
```

Here it is how I am doing validation now:

```
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        //reset variables
        sErrorMessage = string.Empty;

        //create new array of employees
        List<Person> Employees = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person("Steven",30),
            new Person("John",26),
            new Person("Anna",18)
        };

        //first check if value is not null
        if (Employees == null || Employees.Count == 0)
        {
            InsertErrorMessage("Employee array is empty. Nothing to validate!");
        }

        //Data validation
        foreach (var item in Employees)
        {
            if (item.Name == "John")
                InsertErrorMessage("John is not allowed!");

            if (item.Age < 21)
                InsertErrorMessage("Person has to be older than 21!");
        }
    }
```

For me, the only advantage of catching Exceptions in a try-catch block, is that it gives you extra information such as at what line was the error detected, what module gave the error, ...

Nonetheless, I believe that I did not understand the concept and my code with 'proper' error handling (or at least what should look like proper error handling) is incorrect and has to be written in a different manner.

Can someone please help me understand what is the real added benefit of this? Or maybe to share some articles/videos that will explain this?

EDIT:
just a quick thought - maybe Exceptions are not to be used in a validations, but in a processes such as 'StreamReader trying to access locked file', etc...?

Comment: Your "EDIT" statement is correct. Errors and exceptions are different things. Exceptions are things you don't expect to happen. So if you're processing a file with user input, you expect errors (Users make mistakes). Exceptions are things like you said "File doesn't exist," "File is locked," "System is out of memory" etc.

Comment: I see. Does that mean that my technique of validation (storing error messages to a temporary string, which I in the end write to a file) is correct one?

Comment: Do not use exceptions for validation. Use exceptions for exceptional situations that cannot be handled by the code under normal circumstances.

Comment: Throwing and catching exception serves you the way you want but since throwing exceptions can negatively impact performance, maybe Having your own Mechanism as what you did, is a better way of handling that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep your validation approach like you did. Only use exceptions for error handling. If you just look at the names, your validation consists of rules and not exceptions. If something unexpected happens than you would trigger an exception.

A rule of thumb is to not use exceptions to build your program logic.

A quick google also gave me [this code review post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3785) which also briefly discusses error handling vs. validation.

EDIT: One might argue to wrap the code of your `DoStuff()` method in a try/catch block and then store a generic error. That way your program won't crash if something unexpected happens. In that case I actually would use a `catch(Exception ex)` but make sure to log the exception to make your (debugging) life easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually argue that your current implementation is just fine.  If you want to continue the program without bombing out then your method of logging all the messages to a buffer and just flushing at the end is fine.

If you want to stop processing then throwing an exception may be the preferred method.  If you want something a little more verbose in your error messages you could create an file error object where you can store all information you may need and just format the output in the ToString when you are writing out to the file.